# Chrome : Webview not resizing

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am testing the `<webview>` element in Chrome and I have gone through the documentation but I cannot figure out why the `Webview` is not resizing when the parent window does.

**Index.Html**

```
<body>
<webview  src="http://website.com" style="width:1010px; height:700px" minwidth="1010" minheight="700" autosize="on""></webview>

<script src="index.js"></script>
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
'bounds': {
  'width': 1010,
  'height': 700
 }});});
```

**Index.js**

```
$(function() {
function resizeWebView() {
    $('webview').get(0).width = $(window).width();
    $('webview').get(0).height = $(window).height();
}
$(window).resize(resizeWebView);
resizeWebView();
});
```

I tried also removing the `autosize=on` as recommended but it does not work.
Another question how to disable the main window (Embedder) from resizing.
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You should use the [`chrome.app.window.onBoundsChanged`](http://2-42-0.chrome-apps-doc.appspot.com/apps/app_window.html#event-onBoundsChanged) API on the window object returned by `chrome.app.window.create`. Simple implementation:

**background.js**

```
var appWin = null;

chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create(
    'index.html', 
    {'bounds': {'width': 1010, 'height': 700}},
    onWindowCreated
  );
});

function onWindowCreated(win) {
  appWin = win;
  // Resize the webview when the window resizes.
  appWin.onBoundsChanged.addListener(onBoundsChanged);
  // Initialize the webview size once on launch.
  onBoundsChanged();
}

function onBoundsChanged() {
  var webview = document.querySelector('webview');
  var bounds = appWin.getBounds();
  webview.style.height = bounds.height + 'px';
  webview.style.width = bounds.width + 'px';
}
```

**index.js**

```
// Nothing here
```

See a much more elaborate object-oriented example with multiple windows and persisting/reusing the last window size set by the user here: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/url-handler.

As to your second question, it would be good if you asked it separately, but nevertheless: just set the `resizable` parameter of [`chrome.app.window.create`](http://2-42-0.chrome-apps-doc.appspot.com/apps/app_window.html#method-create) to false:

```
  ...
  chrome.app.window.create(
    'index.html', 
    {
      'bounds': {'width': 1010, 'height': 700}, 
      'resizable': false
    },
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I set out to achieve something similar and the following approach is how I implemented it.

### index.html

```
<webview  src="http://website.com" style="width:1010px; height:700px"></webview>
```

### background.js

The code you have here looks correct.

### index.js

I approached this in a slightly different way by using the `window.onresize` event to handle the resize. Please keep in mind that resize event is fired after the screen has been resized and may seem to create a slightly laggy feel.

```
window.onresize = setWebview;

function setWebview() {
    var webview = document.querySelector('webview');
    var webviewWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var webviewHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

    webview.style.width = webviewWidth + 'px';
    webview.style.height = webviewHeight + 'px';
}
```

I also call the `setWebview();` function in the onLoad or something of the sorts for the initial setting of the webview.

So that is my approach, looking at your index.js I think you may be having an issue in that you are trying to set the width and height of the `<webview>` when in fact you need to be setting the style width and height, so maybe the following would have worked;

```
$('webview').get(0).style.width = $(window).width();
$('webview').get(0).style.height = $(window).height();
```

Notice that I added in `.style` before `.width` and `.height`

Hope that helps..

Comment: Chrome Platform APIs provide a better way for this than window.onresize. See my separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a new thing but I did exactly this with CSS:

```
webview {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Easy as pie!